# In a field extension K/F, does K itself need to be a field? Or it can just be a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm a noob in abstract algebra. So, I beg pardon for all my mistakes and misconceptions ahead.

My confusion actually arises considering vector space. As far as I know a vector space V over a field F is just an abelian group which must have one special function: "scalar multiplication" defined.

Now is a vector space over a field can always be considered a field extension? If yes, then it's not always a field. For example $\Bbb R^3$ over $\Bbb R$  is an R-vector space. Is $\Bbb R^3$ an extension field of $\Bbb R$? $\Bbb R^3$ is definitely not a field, as vectors don't have unique inverses. So, if an extension field itself needs to be a field, then $\Bbb R^3$ is not a extension field of $\Bbb R$.

But if in a field extension $K/F$, the extension field $K$ is not necessarily a vector space, then how its possible to measure its size (relative to $F$) with its dimension?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: By an ‘extension field $K/F$’ is simply meant a field $K$ which contains the field $F$ (or a homomorphic image thereof)  as a subfield.

Comment: In fact, there's no degree $3$ extension of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for the links José Carlos Santos. Thanks all for clarification. So what I got is, a field extension is a vector space. But there is no necessity for a vector space to be a field, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector space need not be a field, as you already observed. There is no multiplication of vectors a priori. By definition, a field extension of $F$ is a field $K$ containing $F$. But since a field is in particular an additive group, any such field extension $K$ is in particular an $F$- vector space.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if $V$ is a vector space over $K$, then $V$ is not necessarily a field. Indeed, there need not be defined a multiplication of vectors in $V$, such as in $V={\Bbb R}^2$ over $K={\Bbb R}$.

On the other hand, if $F$ is a field extension of a field $K$, then $F$ is vector space over $K$. This simply follows from the field axioms and the vector space axioms.